# How can I transform user Input exactly as processed data that I used to train the classifier? I want to perform sentiment analysis on user input text

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I want to perform sentiment analysis using NLTK in python on a sentence that is an input from the user as either voice input or text, but I cannot understand how to perform sentiment analysis. I have searched but most of the search results show movie reviews data or twitter sentiment analysis. Kindly help.
The code I used to Train the classifier is as:

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
import pickle

documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category) for category in movie_reviews.categories() for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

random.shuffle(documents)

# print(len(documents))

all_words = []

for word in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(word.lower())

# print(len(all_words))
all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)
# print("First 20 Most Repeated Words are: ", all_words.most_common(20))
# word_in = input("Enter a word to find out how many times it appears in the reveiws:   ")
# print(f"Number of Times the Word {0} Appeared : ".format(word_in), all_words[word_in])

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]




def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    featurs = {}
    for w in word_features:
        featurs[w] = (w in words)
    return featurs

# print(find_features(movie_reviews.words('neg/cv000_29416.txt')))
featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

train_set = featuresets[:1900]

test_set = featuresets[1900:]

# print(test_set[0])


classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

print("Classifier Accuracy: ", (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))*100
```

Instead of `test_set` i want to use my own sentence

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/sentiment-analysis-concept-analysis-and-applications-6c94d6f58c17

Comment: Start with reading about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question, as written, is too general and off topic on SO.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope you can help me now.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

So after training the model, you need to use predict function of the model to get the sentiment of an input sentence.Also you have to make sure that you have transformed your input data exactly as you processed your training data. I know it can be hard trying to understand from comments so Here is a medium article that shows how to predict user input.[Sentiment analysis](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/sentiment-analysis-642b935ab6f9)

Comment: Your answer is too general and, overall, useless.

Comment: I have answered in accordance to the question. I guess i understood what he meant and I think this may not be exactly the answer, but ll help him to get there

Comment: that is the problem I am facing right now, I don't know how to transform my sentence exactly as processed data because I used movie reviews data to train and then saved the classifier.